# OCL function-operation

Tags: uml, modeling, ocl

I need help with an OCL operation to pass one of my master's subject. I do not know much about OCL language.

What I've to do is next:

> Implement the operation:
>
> ```
> Server::validMovement(playerName:String, movement:Movement):bool
> ```
>
> This operation returns true if and only if exists a game who has one of its players with name playerName, that player would have the attribute hasTurn to true and the game board returns true when calling one operation validMovement(movement).
>
> It's supposed that the operation `Board:validMovement(g:Game):bool` exists and it's NOT necessary documentary it in OCL.

Comment: You should make an attempt and post a question here if you have problems.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be something like that? I don't know if it's OK or not...

context Server :: validMovement(namePlayer:String, movement:Movement) : boolean

post : result = self.games->one(g : Game | p. players->exists(p : Player | p.name=namePlayer and p.hasTurn=true) and p.board.validMovement(movement))